# minikube start fails with "libmachine: Error dialing TCP: dial tcp 10.43.239.243:49167: connect: no route to host" error inside docker in docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-in-docker, kubernetes-networking

`minikube start` fails with error `libmachine: Error dialing TCP: dial tcp 10.43.239.243:49167: connect: no route to host` when run in the below setup:

- k8s cluster (with `containerd` as container runtime) with 2 pods: one with docker client container, second with docker daemon container.

`dind` daemon resources:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: dind  
spec:
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: dind
  serviceName: "dind"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dind
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dind-daemon 
          image: docker:20.10.17-dind
          securityContext: 
            privileged: true
          env: 
            - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
              value: ""
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dind  
spec:
  selector:
    app: dind
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: daemon
    protocol: TCP
    port: 2375
    targetPort: 2375
```

`dind` client resources:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "docker-client"
  labels:
    app: "docker-client"
spec:
  containers:
  - name: docker-client
    image: "docker:latest"
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_HOST
      value: "tcp://dind:2375"
```

- `minikube start` runs inside docker client container

How to debug this issue and what might be the reason for it? `10.43.239.243` is ip of `ClusterIP` `dind` service. The error happens after lines in `minikube` log:

```
I0804 09:46:35.049413     222 main.go:134] libmachine: About to run SSH command:
sudo hostname minikube && echo "minikube" | sudo tee /etc/hostname
```

I tried to make the same experiment when both containers run without kubernetes (using docker daemon). In that case, both were using the same `docker` network, daemon container started with `dind` network alias and `minikube start` succeeded.

Below are the used commands:

- docker daemon container:

`docker run --name dind -d --privileged --network dind --network-alias dind -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=""  docker:dind`

- docker client container:

```
docker run --name dind-client -it  --network dind  -e DOCKER_HOST="tcp://dind:2375"docker sh
/ # wget https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
/ # mv minikube-linux-amd64 minikube
/ # chmod +x minikube 
/ # ./minikube start --force
...
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
/ # ./minikube kubectl -- run --image=hello-world
/ # ./minikube kubectl -- logs pod/hello
Hello from Docker!
```